# Как получить значение из массива String

Tags: java, массивы

В классе есть статический массив типа `String`:

```
static String letters []= { "A", "B", "C" };
```

В конструкторе я хочу одному из полей присвоить, скажем, значение `a[1]` из массива выше.

```
myLetter = a[1]; //конечно же не работает
```

Как это оформить?

В программе квадратные скобки были, тут забыл указать.
Проблема была в том, что забыл указать тип переменной которой присваиваю значение.

Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: У вас не массив, вот и не работает. Надо так объявлять: static `String[] letters = { "A", "B", "C" };` или так `static String letters[] = { "A", "B", "C" };`

Comment: `String letters` замените на `String letters[]`. У вас квадратных скобок в объявлении не хватает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Комментарий "конечно же не работает" можно отнести и к первой строке кода, ибо в ней представлен некомпилируемый код.

Если `letters` действительно объявить как массив (`String[]`, а не `String`), а в конструкторе использовать `letters`, а не `a`, то всё работает:

```
public class Element
{
    static String[] letters = { "A", "B", "C" };

    String myLetter;

    public Element()
    {
        myLetter = letters[1];
    }
}
```

---

И не по самому вопросу:

Если массив `letters` не будет меняться, то стоит отметить его как `final`. Если он не должен быть доступен извне (из других классов), то стоит также сделать его `private`. Аналогично для `myLetter`.

Answer (score 0):

У вас не массив, вот и не работает. Надо так объявлять:

```
static String[] letters = { "A", "B", "C" };
```

или так

```
static String letters[] = { "A", "B", "C" };
```